# How do i use validation in admin.py while overriding save_model() function?

Tags: django, django-admin

```
Admin.py

class CourseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

list_display = ('course_code', 'title', 'short' )

 def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    import os

    #obj.author = request.user
    dir_name = obj.course_code
    path = settings.MEDIA_ROOT +os.sep+'xml'+os.sep+dir_name

    #if user updates course name then course would be renames
    if change:
        dir_name = Course.objects.get(pk=obj.pk).course_code
        src = settings.MEDIA_ROOT +os.sep+'xml'+os.sep+dir_name      
        os.rename(src,path)
    else:
        if not os.path.exists(path):
            os.makedirs(path)
            obj.save()

        else:
            raise ValidationError('Bla Bla')


admin.site.register(Course, CourseAdmin)
```

when i raise  validation Error it doesn't work and shows error page with 
Exception Type: Validation Error
Exception Value:[u'Bla Bla']

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per django documentation on [model admin methods](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-methods), the save_model() Must save the object no matter what. You only use this method for performing extra processing before save. I agree with Wogan, you should just create a custom ModelForm and override its clean() method and raise the error there.

Comment: I got your point but can you give me a short example on using validation in Modelform over the values posted by user .The example showed in django documentation for overriding clean() method doesn't shows any validation happening. Thanks

Comment: If you return from `save_model` without calling `obj.save()` it wont save the object.

Comment: timkofu is right. But green SUCCESS message will be shown in admin, as it is kind of unintended hacking.

Answer (score 13):

Do your validation in a custom `ModelForm`, then tell your `ModelAdmin` to use that form.

This part of the [Django Documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-custom-validation-to-the-admin) should help you out.

Comment: How can i pass the current object to ModelForm clean() method to perform validation?

Comment: @anks: Use `self.instance`

Comment: What if we need access to the request object to validate it?

Answer (score 6):

Here's an example:

> ```
> def clean_name(self):
>     if something:
>         raise forms.ValidationError("Something went wrong")
>     return self.cleaned_data["name"]
> ```

Answer (score 6):

you should create a form-

inside your CourseAdminForm:

```
class CourseAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def clean(self):
        raise ValidationError("Bla Bla")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like that

```
from django.contrib import messages

messages.error(request, '<Your message>')
```

it will be saved but user can to see that something is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way to do it, without creating a custom form and then using it:

1.In Your Models.py add "blank=True" for example:

```
Zone_Name = models.CharField(max_length=100L,unique=True,blank=True )
```

2.Create or add to an existing Clean method in the same class of Models.py (not in Admin.py) the validation on the field that you want, for example:

```
def clean(self):
         if self.Zone_Name == None or not self.Zone_Name :
            raise ValidationError("Zone name is not given!")
```

Comment: I gonna try this because I don't want to create a separate Form for no reason (yet again extra plumbing code)

Comment: It works, this is the optimal solution: it adds the validation to a central point, which will have effect on all future forms as well. Besides there's no need to unnecessarily scaffold a custom form!

Answer (score 3):

You should write validation logic in custom form, here is a complete example:

```py
# Created by BaiJiFeiLong@gmail.com at 2022/4/26
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


class UserAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # Show error on username field
    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get("username")
        if len(username) <= 6:
            raise ValidationError("Username is illegal")
        return username

    # Show error on form top
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        if cleaned_data.get("username") == cleaned_data.get("password"):
            raise ValidationError("Password must not be equal to username")
        return cleaned_data


class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = User
    form = UserAdminForm
```

Comment: Unfortunately this raises `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Creating a ModelForm without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute is prohibited; form {form} needs updating.`. But I guess all it needs is `exclude = []`

Comment: This it the way to go, thanks @BaiJiFeiLong. And even better: derive UserAdminForm from django.contrib.auth.forms.UserChangeForm